# WalletConnect disable infura error message

Tags: wallet-connect, decentralized-applications

I am currently developing a dapp and I am integrating walletconnect.

I use this code for connecting:

```js
const chainId = ContractService.getPreferredChainId();
const rpc = ContractService.getRpcAddress();
provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: undefined,
  rpc: {
    [chainId]: rpc,
  },
});
await provider.enable();
```

`chainId` is dynamically chosen based on if the app is in development mode or not. while in development it runs on chain id `97`.
RPC is the same story, it just gets the binance smart chain RPC JSON provider.

Connecting works well, but I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix this without making an infura account? Or is that required..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

make sure to add a `chainId` to the object like this:

```js
new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: undefined,
  rpc: {
    1: "https://RPC_URL",
  },
  chainId: 1
});
```

Then it should work without issues, you can even omit the `infuraId` field